# Clicks not code and Salesforce Contacts?

Tags: salesforce, contacts, salesforce-service-cloud

So I've got a group of users who originally were going to use one custom object and nothing else, and now their team wants a Case system and the whole shebang.

A Case means a Contact, which lives under the account. The Trouble is everything else these users do is driven from that one custom object they use, which isn't tied into the case system. This leaves my users with exactly the problem described here: https://www.buttonclickadmin.com/salesforce-visual-workflow-advanced-flows/

In other words, Lots and lots of extra effort to find an account, check for a contact and then either use it or make a contact.

Now, if I had a primary key (like the email) that I could count on 100% I'd use a flow like that other guy did. But I don't. Lots of the case contacts don't have email or just plain won't give it (or worse use a group email). AFAIK Record Lookups in a flow only pull one record.

I could fix this with some snazzy VisualForce + Apex. I could take the Id from that one custom object the users have and give them a custom search. I could probably tag the Contact with that Id too (I'm trying not to, it's a big org and it's a pain to get permission to update Standard Objects).

Am I missing something? Why are Case Contacts such a pain to create and manage for users? I understand that the workflow of Account -> Contact -> Case helps prevent duplicates, but it's incredibly confusing to tell my users "Don't go to the Case Tab when you want a case, find the account first".

Comment: What would be an ideal solution for your situation? Would you prefer to simply not tie cases to contacts, or a better contact search mechanism?

Comment: The idea situation would let me prompt the user for a Serial Number, let them pick a contact associated with the serial number (or create a new one) then give them a case. I'm finding that I can more or less do that with Flows + URL hacking and it's not so bad. I prompt the User for a Serial Number, look up a custom Product object that ties the Serial Number to an account and then show a list of contacts. It gets a little hairy with all the HTML & URLs to move the user around, but it works. The HTML+URLs+field references border on code, but it's not Apex :).